# Can I use the 'Use' operator from a different PHP file?

Tags: php, class, require

I have this code here which will be used quite a lot throughout my app:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/parse/autoload.php');

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
```

I placed all of that code in a file called parse.php, however when I attempt to include that file use classes aren't being found.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'ParseClient' not found in /xxx/xxx/xxx.php on line 11

Comment: I need to now your file structure.

Comment: I am using codeigniter and loading the file right before some model classes. The file is definitely being loaded using require_once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use doesn't include anything. It just imports the specified namespace (or class) to the current scope.
If you want the classes to be autoloaded - read about autoloading functionality of PHP(http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Comment: I know it doesn't include anything, but why is it when I place the code in a separate file, I get error, however if I replace require_once "parse.php" with the code above, it works absolutely fine?

Comment: You'll have to include/require the class anyway, otherwise PHP won't know about the namespace.

Comment: I do, if you look at my code I include the file that calls all the classes (the autoload.php)